# Ruby churn requires churn (>= 0) on installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metrical, churn

I am trying to install metrical and it fails with

```
gem install metrical
ERROR:  Error installing metrical:
    churn requires churn (>= 0)
```

Trying the following also gives errors.

```
gem install churn 
ERROR:  Error installing churn:
    churn requires churn (>= 0)
```

Does anyone knows how to install churn when churn requires itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem will not install properly through commandline because of its dependencies.
https://github.com/iain/metrical/#usage

If you are working on rails app just add it in Gemfile

```
gem 'metrical', :require => false
```

then `bundle install`

this will install it will all proper dependencies

or else to install it from outside rails.

Create a `Gemfile` in any dummy direcory and add following lines

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'metrical'
```

then run `bundle install`

worked for me.. Cheers

Comment: Worked for me also. But now the next problem - running metrical results in "/home/kireto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb:279: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)". But that is another question

Comment: glad that helped. there are many question on STO regarding your next problem :) happy coding.